# Svelte "router.reload" does not update data every time

Tags: laravel, svelte, inertiajs, svelte-3

In Svelte (using Laravel 9, Svelte via Inertia), I have built a component **"BookmarkButton.svelte"**.
In this component, I am executing a function **"handleBookmark"** when the button is clicked. This function calls an **API request** to my route resposible for updating my AccountHasBookmarks table, "POST /bookmarks/" or "POST /bookmarks/delete/" depending on the state of my object that I'm trying to bookmark/delete bookmark. After that request, I am executing **"router.reload()"** in order to update the data used by the view.
The component is meant to be used inside of different objects which can be bookmarked. The problem is that when I click on the button inside of my Svelte page resposible for displaying all bookmarks "Bookmakrs.svelte", **most of the time** it does **not update the list of bookmarks in the view**. Sometimes it does work however, which is why I think that this problem is caused by asynchronous code execution somewhere along all my code. On a manual page reload, it always displays the correct bookmarks.

BookmarksButton.svelte:

```
<script>
    import { page, router } from '@inertiajs/svelte';
    import axios from 'axios';
    export let checkId;

    let bookmarks = $page.props.bookmarks;
    $: isChecked = bookmarks?.find(bookmark => bookmark.BOOKMARK_ID == checkId);

    let handleBookmark = () => {
        if(isChecked){
            axios.post('/bookmarks/delete/' + checkId)
            .then((x)=>{
                router.reload();
            });
        } else {
            axios.post('/bookmarks/' + checkId)
            .then((x)=>{
                router.reload();
            });
        }
    }

    let isHovering = false;
</script>

{#if $page.props.auth.user}
        <button on:click={handleBookmark} class="tw-py-0.5 tw-px-3 tw-rounded-3xl tw-bg-yellow-400 tw-text-black" on:click={() => {isChecked = !isChecked}}
            on:mouseover={() => isHovering = true}
                    on:mouseout={() => isHovering = false}>
            {#if isChecked}
                <i
                    class:hover={isHovering ? 'bi bi-bookmark-fill' : ''}
                    class={isHovering ? 'bi bi-bookmark' : 'bi bi-bookmark-fill'}
                    
                ></i>
            {:else}
                <i
                    class:hover={isHovering ? 'bi bi-bookmark' : ''}
                    class={isHovering ? 'bi bi-bookmark-fill' : 'bi bi-bookmark'}
                ></i>
            {/if}
        </button>
{/if}
```

Bookmarks.svelte:

```
<script>
    import Layout from "../Shared/Layout.svelte";
    import EventListItem from "../Shared/EventListItem.svelte";
    import FacilityListItem from "../Shared/FacilityListItem.svelte";
    import { page, router } from '@inertiajs/svelte';

    export let bookmarks = $page.props.bookmarks;
    $: events = bookmarks.filter(bookmark => bookmark.event !== null).map(bookmark => bookmark.event);
    $: facilities = bookmarks.filter(bookmark => bookmark.facility !== null).map(bookmark => bookmark.facility);
</script>

<Layout>

            {#each events as event}
                <EventListItem event={event}/>
            {/each}
            {#each facilities as facility}
                <FacilityListItem facility={facility}/>
            {/each}
</Layout>
```

FacilityListItem.svelte:

```
<script>
    export let facility;
    import { inertia } from '@inertiajs/svelte';
    import BookmarkButton from './BookmarkButton.svelte';
</script>

<div class="tw-border tw-rounded-md tw-bg-slate-50 tw-p-4 tw-mt-4 tw-grid tw-grid-cols-1 sm:tw-grid-cols-2 lg:tw-grid-cols-4 tw-gap-4">
    <img class="tw-shadow tw-rounded-md tw-overflow-hidden tw-h-40 tw-object-cover tw-w-full" src="/images/uploads/{facility.IMAGE_PATH}" alt="{facility.NAME}">
    <div>
        <span use:inertia="{{ href: "/facilities/"+facility.FACILITY_ID, method: 'get' }}" class="tw-block tw-text-2xl tw-font-medium tw-underline-offset-4 tw-decoration-1 tw-cursor-pointer tw-underline tw-mb-3 hover:tw-no-underline">{facility.NAME}</span>
        {facility.FACILITY_TYPE}
        <BookmarkButton checkId={facility.FACILITY_ID} />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Website</h4>
        <a href="{facility.WEBSITE_URL}" class="tw-underline">{facility.WEBSITE_URL}</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Contact</h4>
        Address
        {facility.ADDRESS}, {facility.POSTAL_CODE} {facility.CITY}<br>
        E-Mail
        {facility.EMAIL}
    </div>
</div>
```

web.php:

```
    Route::post('bookmarks/delete/{id}', [BookmarkController::class, 'deleteBookmark'])->middleware('isBookmarkOwnerWeb');
    Route::post('bookmarks/{id}', [BookmarkController::class, 'createBookmark']);
```

BookmarkController.php:

```
    public function deleteBookmark($id)
    {
        $bookmark = AccountHasBookmarks::find(['ACCOUNT_ID' => request()->user()->ACCOUNT_ID, 'BOOKMARK_ID' => $id]);
        $bookmark->delete();
    }

    public function createBookmark($id)
    {
        $bookmark = AccountHasBookmarks::create(['ACCOUNT_ID' => request()->user()->ACCOUNT_ID, 'BOOKMARK_ID' => $id]);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there might be some asynchronous code running in your component. To solve this, I suggest using Promise.all() which allows for the concurrent execution of multiple promises. This could be the solution to your problem!!!

You can check the following URL: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-promise-all-method/